# Pagination in category

Tags: plugins, categories, pagination

**Updated:** 
**I have 50 categories and i wants to show each 5 category on one page and next 5 on next page and next 5 on next page. and so on. with pagination.**

I have 50 categories in a WordPress site. I wants to show five categories on every page with pagination with 10 post. I have tried but pagination is not creating.

```
<?php 
    // get all the categories from the database
    $cats = get_categories();
    // loop through the categries
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
    // setup the cateogory ID
    $cat_id= $cat->term_id;
    // Make a header for the cateogry
    ?>
        <div class="cats-by-2">
            <div class="cat-posts-left">
                <h2 class="feat-title"><span><a href=""><?php echo '<h2>'.$cat->name.'</h2>'; ?></a></span></h2>
                    <div class="posts-by-3">
                <?php
                // create a custom wordpress query
                query_posts("cat=$cat_id");
                $count = 1;

                if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                    <div class="post-wrap<?php if ($count%3 == 0) { ?> right<?php } ?>">

                        <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-main-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                        <div class="entry clearfix">

                            <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="<?php _e("bookmark", "solostream"); ?>" title="<?php _e("Permanent Link to", "solostream"); ?> <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                        </div>
                        <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . "/postinfo.php"); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php if ( $count%3 == 0 ) { ?>
                <div class="post-clear"></div>
<?php } ?>

                    <?php $count = $count + 1 ?>
                <?php endwhile; endif;
                // done our wordpress loop. Will start again for each category ?>

            </div></div>

        </div>
<?php } // done the foreach statement ?>
```

Comment: It is really not clear what you are trying to do. Please explain in human terms exactly what the result should be.

Comment: I have 50 categories and i wants to show each 5 category on one page and next 5 on next page and next 5 on next page. and so on. with pagination

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use [`query_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts).

1. There are no pagination functions that I can spot in your code. That
   is a big problem if you want pagination to work.
2. Nor do you have a pagination parameter in your `query_posts` (which
   you should not be using) arguments.
3. The simple pagination functions like [`next_posts_link`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) may not
   work in your case anyway, without complicated filtering, as those rely on the main query and you are paginating something other than that query.

Plus, I don't see how you are even attempting to break these into fives (%3 is not going to do that ??).

I don't really see how that code is even an attempt to do what you describe, but here is an outline to get you started in the right direction. I have not made any effort to duplicate the markup you need. You should be able to work that into the Loop yourself.

```
// set pagination
$page = (!empty($_GET['catp'])) ? $_GET['catp'] : 1; 
// pull catagories
$cats = get_categories();
// break them into blocks of 5  
$cats = array_chunk($cats,5); 
// grab the five category IDs we need for the query 
$ids = wp_list_pluck($cats[$page - 1],'term_id');
// query for the posts in those categories
$args = array(
  'category__in' => $ids,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
);
$incats = new WP_Query($args);
// Minimal Loop; proof of concept only
if ($incats->have_posts()) {
  while ($incats->have_posts()) {
    $incats->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<br/>';
  }
}
// paginate
$page_args = array(
    'base'         => '%_%',
    'format'       => '?catp=%#%',
    'total'        => count($cats),
    'current'      => $page,
    'show_all'     => False,
    'end_size'     => 1,
    'mid_size'     => 2,
    'prev_next'    => True,
    'prev_text'    => __('« Previous'),
    'next_text'    => __('Next »'),
    'type'         => 'plain',
);
echo paginate_links($page_args);
```

Comment: thnx. i is very help full to me. I have tried. but category is repeating in pagination. and also prev navigation is not working fine.

Comment: You've done something wrong or your theme or a plugin is breaking it. That code works. I have tested it-- WordPress 3.5.1 and Twenty Twelve. Please try it _exactly_ as I posted it.